# how to add external css in facebook tab pages?

Tags: facebook, tabs, fbml

how to add external css in facebook tab pages?

I am adding tab in my facebook pages, now I want to know to add external style sheet I have tried  but it is not working

Comment: I think you mean to create a tab app, which is an iframe and loads an external HTML file from another location. Note you need a SSL certificate on that domain.

Comment: Is is that do I have to use https, If someone doesnt have SSl on its domain then?

Comment: It could be, by default Facebook loads through **https**, when there are resources (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc...) on the current page which are not loaded through https, it'll fire security warnings or not even show the resource. Can you show us some more code?

Comment: And, more importantly, can you explain us which resources you are loading and if they are external through which protocol (http / https) are you trying to load them?

Answer (score 0):

im pretty sure it is just the same as HTML

```
<link href="yourcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

put that at the top of your html, obviously changing the ref to your css

Comment: are you sure that you have got the name of your css correct and definatly have it saved as css? i know its stupid but i saved mine as a txt once. Maybe try without double quotes " and have singles '

Comment: also, not sure if it is the same but i am in the process of creating a canvas app on facebook and i have the security certificate, not sure if it is the same as what Ambidex was referring to

Comment: i did have the correct path for css on my server. Could http and https makes any difference?